# lastElementChild returns null

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Javascript assignment that splits the page into two div elements then appends the div on the left with randomly placed images, then I used `.cloneNode()` to duplicate on the right, minus the last child image.

That part of it works fine, but I am then supposed to add an event handler to the last element of the left div, but when I try to do this the `lastElementChild()` method returns null even though the div has the expected child nodes. The code is below and I've commented where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    img {position: absolute}
    div {position: absolute; height: 500px; width: 500px}
    #right {border-left: solid black; left: 500px}
</style>

<script>

<!-- everything here works fine -->

    function generateFaces(){

        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("left");

        var numberFaces = 5;

        for (i = 0; i < numberFaces; i++){
            var random_x = Math.random()*400;
            var random_y = Math.random()*400;
            var image = document.createElement("img")
            image.src = "smile.png";
            image.setAttribute("style","top: " + random_y + "px;" + "left: " + random_x + "px;");
            theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
        }

        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("right");

        leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
        theRightSide.lastChild.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild.lastChild);
    }


</script>

</head>
<body onload = "generateFaces()">
    <h1> Game </h1>
    <p> Instructions </p>

    <div id = "right"></div>

    <div id = "left"> </div>

    <script>

    <!-- problem script here -->

    var temp = document.getElementById("left");
    console.log(temp); // displays <div> with its children <img>

    var temp2 = temp.lastElementChild;
    console.log(temp2); // returns null

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `generateFaces()` is called after you `console.log(temp2)`. When you're logging, `#left` is still an empty `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body's `onload` event will not fire until after the javascript in your 'problem script' runs.

The order of execution here is basically:

- `h1`, `p`, `#left`, and `#right` get appended to the DOM
- script #1 runs, logging the empty `#left` div and the `null` lastElementChild.
- body `onload` event fires and script #2 runs (the `generateFaces()` function). At this point, the `<img>` tags are inserted into the DOM.

The fix is to make sure that script #1 runs after #2:

```
<body onload="handleLoad()">
```

and the JS:

```
function handleLoad() {
    generateFaces()
    logStuff()
}

function logStuff() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("left");
    console.log(temp); // displays <div> with its children <img>

    var temp2 = temp.lastElementChild;
    console.log(temp2); // logs <img>
}
```

It might appear, in the console, that `#left` has images in it at the time that script #1 runs. This is just a quirk of the console; the actual logging happens asynchronously, and since the referenced variable changes in the meantime, the value actually logged is different than what it was when `console.log()` was called.

You can see this behavior by varying a `setTimeout` duration on the `generateFaces()` function call:

```js
function generateFaces() {

    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("left");

    var numberFaces = 5;

    for (i = 0; i < numberFaces; i++) {
        var random_x = Math.random() * 400;
        var random_y = Math.random() * 400;
        var image = document.createElement("img")
        image.src = "smile.png";
        image.setAttribute("style", "top: " + random_y + "px;" + "left: " + random_x + "px;");
        theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
    }

    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("right");

    leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
    theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
    theRightSide.lastChild.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild.lastChild);
}


var temp = document.getElementById("left");
console.log(temp); // displays <div> with its children <img>

var temp2 = temp.lastElementChild;
console.log(temp2); // returns null


setTimeout(generateFaces, 250) // play with this value
```

```css
img {
    position: absolute
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px
}

#right {
    border-left: solid black;
    left: 500px
}
```

```html
<h1> Game </h1>
<p> Instructions </p>

<div id="right"></div>

<div id="left"> </div>
```

Oh, and note that your `generateFaces()` function currently creates multiple elements in the DOM with the same id. You're gonna want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your generateFaces() function is called when the **body is loaded**.
but your second script runs when the **window is loaded**.

So when the second script runs there is no **temp.lastElementChild** and you get null.

You can slove is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<style>
img {position: absolute, height: 30px; width: 30px;}
div {position: absolute; height: 500px; width: 500px}
#right {border-left: solid black; left: 500px}
</style>
</head>
<body onload = "generateFaces()">
<h1> Game </h1>
<p> Instructions </p>

<div id = "right"></div>

<div id = "left"> </div>
<script>


function generateFaces()
{
    console.log('y');
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("left");

    var numberFaces = 5;

    for (i = 0; i < numberFaces; i++){
        var random_x = Math.random()*400;
        var random_y = Math.random()*400;
        var image = document.createElement("img")
        image.src = "smile.png";
        image.setAttribute("style","top: " + random_y + "px;" + "left: " + random_x + "px;");
        theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
    }

    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("right");

    leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
    theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

    theRightSide.lastChild.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild.lastChild);

    loaded();

}
```

```
<script>

 function loaded() {


var temp = document.getElementById("left");
console.log(temp); 

var temp2 = temp.lastElementChild;
console.log(temp2);
```

}